# External Page Content Overflows out of Bootstrap Modal

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have the following Modal:

```
 <a href="somepage.htm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#extLinkModal">

<div class="modal fade" id="extLinkModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="extlinkModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static">
        <div class="modal-dialog " role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                  <h4 class="modal-title" id="extLinkModalLabel"></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">


            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

When I click the link to launch modal, the content of somepage.htm overflows out of the modal and there are no scroll bars on the modal?

How come this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have 2 pages, `index.htm` and `somepage.htm`

you have modal in page `index.htm` and you want to show `somepage.htm` inside modal. Then

index.htm page code will be

```
<a href="somepage.htm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#extLinkModal">

<div class="modal fade" id="extLinkModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="extlinkModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog " role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
         //Here you can show the content from `somepage.htm`
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and somepage.htm page content will be

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
      <h4 class="modal-title" id="extLinkModalLabel"></h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
  //Put the page content here
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</div>
```

This will resolve the issue *somepage.htm overflows out of the modal and there are no scroll bars on the modal*

**Alternate Solution**

OP asked in comments to load the remote page content into `modal-body` and above code example is default behavior of bootstrap v3+ where modal ignores the `modal-body` and always load the remote content into `<div class="modal-content">` doesn't matter even if `<div class="modal-body">` exist inside the `<div class="modal-content">`.

To get around this and make sure that the remote content load inside `<div class="modal-body">`

1. Use bootstrap modal [events](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events)
2. Do not use `href` or `remote` in modal call button or link

So the modal call button or link will be

```
<a datalink="somepage.htm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#extLinkModal" class="btn btn-primary">
```

where `href` changed to `datalink` or any word can be used but not `href` or `remote` otherwise modal will detect it as remote content and ignores the `<div class="modal-body">` and load the content into `<div class="modal-content">`

Modal HTML

```
<div class="modal fade" id="extLinkModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="extlinkModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog " role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
              <h4 class="modal-title" id="extLinkModalLabel"></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            //Remote Page Content loads here
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and JS

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#extLinkModal").on("show.bs.modal", function(e) {
        var link = $(e.relatedTarget);
        $(this).find(".modal-body").load(link.attr("datalink"));
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: But I wish to show the entire page of somepage.htm. In otherwords I'm trying to load an external page similar to how I would load a page in an iframe. How can I do that without having to add the modal body in every page I wish to load?

Answer (score 0):

The content of somepage.htm overflows out of the modal because your somepage.htm page is not responsive, and your modal have some fixed height and width. So try to make your page responsive using bootstrap classes and some additional css if needed.

So making somepage.htm page content responsive will solve both problems of content overflows out of the modal as well as scroll bar.
Hope it will help you!